# ASP.Net Web Api Serialization Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In Web Api project when I enter url *localhost:[portnumber]/api/os*, I get long XML file containing errors, here is Exception Message:

Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CollegeCourse_C7F37B1980970AF17607E96F17DFE50E3A680141BF8228EEA7D39A9150498388' with data contract name 'CollegeCourse_C7F37B1980970AF17607E96F17DFE50E3A680141BF8228EEA7D39A9150498388:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

But when I enter url localhost: *[portnumber]/api/role* everything is fine, here is code:

OS:

```
public class UserOS
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserOSId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string OSType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Role:

```
public class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

And API controller for Role and OS is similar, so I'll paste for Role only:

```
  private CompeteDataBase _competeDataBase = new CompeteDataBase();

   public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetAllRoles()
   {
       return _competeDataBase.UserRoles.AsEnumerable();
   }
```

**Edit**

Is it correct way to use DTOs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to solve problem, I don't know how or why but deleting database and crating in again solved everything (I didn't change anything else)

Does anyone maybe know why ???

Answer (score 6):

This is because EntityFramework creates a 'proxy' of your class.

To make this work, simply disable the proxy creation. You can go into your Context constructor and add the following:

```
ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I've added these two lines to my DbContext constructor

            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      
But i get same error

Comment: can you check in you debuggers, look into the object to be return and make sure that the object proxy is not create

Comment: It wasn't that, somehow I solved problem by deleting a database and creating it again :/